# Get the count of items in a GroupBy Linq-to-sql Query?

Tags: linq-to-sql, count, group-by

I have a GroupBy that I groups all elements. I can see the items are there in LinqPad but can't find a way to get the count.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SurveyResponses.Where( q => q.QuestionId == 4)
    .GroupBy(q => q.AnswerNumeric)
    .Where( g => g.Key == 1)
```

In Linq Pad I can see there are 4 items in this query. If I do Count it returns 1.

I've tried, `ToList().Count`, `Select(x => x).Count`, etc.

To be clear, I have an IGrouping and need to get the count from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you posted you don't have an `IGrouping<int, Response>`, you have an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Response>>`. You are counting the number of groupings that fulfil the `Where` predicate.

Use `Single` instead of `Where` to get the result you expect:

```
int count = SurveyResponses
    .Where(q => q.QuestionId == 4)
    .GroupBy(q => q.AnswerNumeric)
    .Single(g => g.Key == 1)
    .Count();
```